# Jquery Carousel Displaying one post multiple time

Tags: jquery, carousel

I am using the following jQuery carousel for displaying 4 posts. I have 6 posts . It is working fine. But when I click on next button the next 2 posts along with the posts in the first slide is appearing.

```
jQuery(function($) {
$('#foo2').carouFredSel({
    prev: '#prev2',
    next: '#next2',
    auto: false,
    items: 4,
});
});
```

the following images will show you exactly what happens.
[image]
This Image Shows what happens on page load.

[image]
This is what happen when clicking on next.

Someone please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your carousel is behaving in a circular mode, turn off the circular and things will work as expected.

```
jQuery(function($) {
$('#foo2').carouFredSel({
    prev: '#prev2',
    next: '#next2',
    circular: false,
    infinite: false,
    auto: false,
    items: 4,
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that.. It worked like a charm. Another thing is that I need to show the next 2 only not the others. Here what happens is the first one will hide and the next will appear. I need all first 4 to hide and next posts to appear. If it is only one just one should appear not 4

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function($) {
$('#foo2').carouFredSel({
    prev: '#prev2',
    next: '#next2',
    auto: false,
    items: 4,
    circular:false
});
});
```

Try `circular:false`

Comment: Thanks for that.. It worked like a charm. Another thing is that I need to show the next 2 only not the others. Here what happens is the first one will hide and the next will appear. I need all first 4 to hide and next posts to appear. If it is only one just one should appear not 4